# Поменять местами первый max и первый min элементы 2d массива в C

Tags: c++, c

В общем суть вопроса такова, я успешно нашел минимальный и максимальный элементы массива, а также смог их поменять местами. Но у меня есть дополнительные условия задания, которые я никак не могу понять как выполнить. Если их( элементов) несколько, тогда первый мин заменить первым максимальным и последний максимальный последним минимальным.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: 2d - это двумерный массив? типо матрицы?

Comment: Да, 2d -двумерный.
Допустим у меня максимальный элемент это 9, а мин 2. 9 встречается три раза на разных позициях и двойка 2 раза на разных позициях. Нужно заменить первый встречающийся минимальный заменить первым встречабщимся максимальным и далее по такой же логике

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы используете при поиске строгое условие, a[i]>a[zmax], то найдётся первый максимум.

Если вы используете при поиске не строгое условие, a[i]>=a[zmax], то найдётся последний максимум.

Например для массива 1,2,1,2 в первом случае найдется минимум с номером 0, и максимум с номером 1,а во втором случае найдётся минимум с номером 2 и максимум с номером 3.